# Get the low portion of a number of any of the built-in types

Tags: c++

How would I create a function template which returns the low portion of a number of N bits?
For example, for an 8 bit number, get the least significant 4 bits, for a 16 bit number, get the least significant 8 bits.

Comment: Show us your efforts, and we will help you with the missing bits. Dumping homework on us is not going to help you.

Comment: Why do you need a `template`?  Just use the `&` and a masking value.  IMHO, a template for this would add extra complexity and development time.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, how would you solve the problem (a number of **N** bits) without a template in C++?

Comment: A `template` would allow various data types like, `long`, `std::string`, `std::vector` and other structures.  Another reason not to use a template.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, a template would allow various types, such as `long`, `long long`, `int`, `short int` and `char`. This is the very description of the problem!

Comment: @SergeyA: I would use `*variable_name* & MASK_SIZE` using the variable.  For larger bit sizes, I would use a big number library.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews un sure how you would do it in a function. Perhaps you can provide an answer to the question?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It will only allow data types that have an `&` operator.

Comment: @Aureal:  If you could limit the maximum size of the number, the solution could be simplified.  However with the meaning of `N` being any positive size (that a platform can support), the algorithm becomes more complicated.

Comment: I need a template because this function is to be used on some kind of a utilities header, not for a specific problem. @SergeyA why do you assume that I'm "dumping homework"? I'm not even in college yet, and yes, if I'm asking this here, its because I wasn't able to do this for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the lower half of a built-in integer type you can try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T>
constexpr T lowbits(T v) {
    return v & (T(1) << CHAR_BIT * sizeof v / 2) - 1;
}

int main() {
    cout << std::hex << (int)lowbits<int8_t>(0xde) << endl; // will print e
    cout << std::hex << lowbits<int16_t>(0xdead) << endl; // will print ad
    cout << std::hex << lowbits<int32_t>(0xdeadbeef) << endl; // will print beef
    cout << std::hex << lowbits<int64_t>(0xbeefdeaddeadbeef) << endl; // will print deadbeef
}
```

Note that

```
return v & (T(1) << CHAR_BIT * sizeof v / 2) - 1;
```

is equivalent to:

```
return v & (
             (static_cast<T>(1) 
             <<
             (CHAR_BIT * (sizeof v) / 2)) // number of bits divided by 2
             - 1
            );
```

In essence you are creating a bit-mask (simply another integer) that has 0-bits for all higher bits and 1-bits for all lower bits.

If an integer type has `N` bits this is done by shifting a 1-bit into the `N`th position and then subtracting `1` from it. The subtraction has the result that all bits below the `1` will be set.

And-ing this with the given value yields only the lower half of the value `v`.

You can easily generalize this approach to retrieving any number of lower bits by replacing `CHAR_BIT * sizeof v/2` with the number of bits you want to retrieve.

To get only the higher bits you can simply negate the resulting mask using the `~` operator.

If you require arbitrary sized integers you can try finding the equivalent operations for this procedure in the [GNU gmp library](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: How do you specify how many low order bits and the number?  Your function only has one parameter.

Comment: How do you account for large bitwidth numbers, let's say 1024?  The OP said `N` sized bits.

Comment: With lower bits I am assuming they mean the lower half of the value.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There's not currently a C++ type for 1024-bit numbers.

Comment: With a 64-bit number, the lower half is 32-bits.  If I only want the low order 3 bits, what do I do?

Comment: OP did not specifically mention arbitrary sized integers so I assumed they only want to use builtin types.

Comment: If you only want the lower 3 bits you have to modify the function

Comment: @Barmar:  I understand, which is why I picked 1024, again the OP said `N` bits.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I think, you are nitpicking. Although OP didn't specify so, I also understood the question as getting lower **half** of the built-in integral type. On a side note, I am still waiting for your non-template solution.

Comment: I feel like the question does not warrant an answer for arbitrary sized integers as that would require at least mentioning what library they are using to represent them.

Comment: This is just what I needed. with N bits I mean all built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define a variable called `mask` which is the pattern to mask off (or retain) some bits.  The operation to get the least significant bits is:
`result = value & mask;`

For an example, test with `value` == 13 and `mask` == 7.

This works will all POD types, except for floating point.  The least significant Q bits of a floating point, doesn't make sense (unless you really need to do this).

If you have no need for more bits than the largest internal integral type, you could use something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T low_bits(T data, size_t bit_count)
{
  T mask = (1U << bit_count) - 1U;
  return value & mask;
}
```

For a non-template solution, one could use a macro:

```
#define LOW_BITS(value, bit_count) \
    (value & ((1U << bit_count) - 1U))
```

This lets the compiler figure out the code based on the data type of `value`.
A macro form of the expression: `value & mask`.

The thorn or issue comes into play when `N > sizeof(*largest type*)`.  In this case, the number can't be represented by internal data types, so one has to come up with a different solution.

The solution for `N`-bit depends on whether the multi-byte representation of the number is Big Endian or Little Endian.  For Big Endian platforms, the least significant value will be at highest address, while on Little Endian platforms, the least significant is at the lowest address.

The solution I'm proposing treats the `N-bit` number as an array of bytes.  A byte contains 8-bits (on most platforms), and bytes can be masked differently than multibyte quantities.

Here's the algorithm:
1. Copy the least significant bytes that are completely masked to the result variable.
2. Mask the next largest byte and copy result byte to result number.
3. Pad remaining bytes with 0.

As far as the function parameters go, you'll need:
1) Pointer to the memory location of the original number.
2) Pointer to the result number.
3) Pointer to the mask.
4) Size of the number, in bytes.

The algorithm can handle `N-bit` numbers, limited by the amount of memory on the platform.

*Note:  sorry about not providing code, but I need to get back to work. :-(*

Comment: The answer you were critiquing only works for built-in types, yet your solution has the same limitation. If you're using built-in types, why does `bit_count` need to be an explicit parameter, since the number of bits is known?

Comment: @Barmar: I'm not finished. :-)

Comment: Reading your answer made me realize what issues you were having with my response. I've adjusted parts of it accordingly.